# use Aspect Fit mode with Draw-in-Rect method

Tags: iphone, ipad

i want to use Aspect Fit Mode in Draw in Rect Method.

```
[mainImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,mainImageView.frame.size.width,mainImageView.frame.size.height)];
```

when i show an image in MainImage View it show in scale to fill mode . I want to show it in Aspect to Fit Mode. how can i do it.can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Implement it in below way:

UIImageView *imgBg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 195.0, 39.0)];

[imgBg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_dropdown.png"]];

[imgBg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers

Comment: First, you can change the value of "CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 195.0, 39.0)" according to X & Y and Width & Height of your image. Then you can use any of the 3 properties like UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill OR UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to mention

```
[self addSubview:imgBg];
```

at the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

If all what you want is just:

> I want to show it in Aspect to Fit Mode

You can set content mode of your Image View:

```
mainImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But if you want your image to be drawn in the graphics context with that content mode, you can draw the whole view instead of using `drawInRect`:

```
mainImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[mainImageView drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds 
                    afterScreenUpdates:NO];
```